# What are some potential challenges of creating random numbers in a parallel computing environment compared to a non parallel computing environment?

Tags: random

I'd like to know why it is considered to be more difficult to generate random numbers when using parallel computing like multi threading or the GPU? Wouldn't it be for instance possible to just start a bunch of threads, give everyone a seed and call it a day? Why is considered to be more difficult?

I know that the topic of RNG itself is considered a big challenge in computer science but why does it get even more difficult when working in a parallel computing environment? Could anyone summarize some reasons?

Sources I consumed but not understood in depth which hint that it's not a trivial topic:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qO8FAQvlgX0&t=1498s
https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/parallel-rng-imacs.pdf

---

Edit: Original question was: "Why is it considered to be difficult to generate random numbers in a parallel computer environment"? Rephrased it due to missing rigor regarding the term 'difficult'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A parallel computer can create individual random numbers just fine; same as single-CPU (or low-multithreading/processing) computers.

The issue is more in the "management" side of it; specifically, to get repeatable streams of (pseudo) random numbers, which is important for repeatable simulations; and hardware limitations like the size of local RAM stores.

The paper you linked has a quite long introduction which explains the kind of problem that they are trying to solve in detail. The most quotable part is this:

> Most good RNGs proposed over the past decades have been designed for
>   single-processor environments with plenty of memory. Some popular ones
>   have a very large state (e.g., [11, 54, 63]), which makes them inappropriate for
>   computations on a single PE having limited fast memory, such as the PEs on
>   discrete GPUs, and adds overhead when storing and restoring stream states,
>   which is required, e.g., to checkpoint programs and restart them from a saved
>   checkpoint, an essential activity in highly-parallel computations.

So, it is not an issue of being "difficult" per se, but that there simply are different architectural limitations within these (GP)GPUs, or in hardware solutions focused on parallelism. In this case, specifically, the good RNGs need large amounts of storage, and the individual processing units of the GPUs have only little available - so a naive approach of just running a good old single-CPU RNG in a GPU thread simply runs out of memory.

They then describe alternative approaches to handle those streams of repeatable random numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, that helps. I guess the term "difficult" might be a bit of a mistake in this context. I tried to rephrase my question to be more appropriate. I got the point though!

Comment: @LOLWTFasdasdasdad, I've rephrased my first sentence to be more appropriate to your rephrasing. Glad that the answer was helpful.